# Pagination while keeping the filters

Tags: filters, pagination

I code a page that shows the post results with a couple of filters (the visitor can filter by country and time) and the result is paginated:

```
$posts_per_page = 10;
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$query_args = array('posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 'paged' => $paged ,  "enable_filter" => array("country", "time"));
$query = WP_Query ($query_args);
$total_post = $query->found_posts;
$pages = $total_post / $posts_per_page;
if ($total_post % $posts_per_page) $pages=$pages+1; 
$args = array(
    'base'               => '%_%',
    'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
    'total'              => $pages,
    'current'            => 0,
    'show_all'           => true,
    'end_size'           => 1,
    'mid_size'           => 2,
    'prev_next'          => true,
    'prev_text'          => __('« Previous'),
    'next_text'          => __('Next »'),
    'type'               => 'plain',
    'add_args'           => false,
    'add_fragment'       => '',
    'before_page_number' => '',
    'after_page_number'  => ''
);
echo paginate_links($args);
?>
```

The pagination works just fine, the problem is when I apply a filter. When I filter by country and/or time the pagination for the results shows right but when I click on page number 2 I get all the results, meaning that the filters are not applied any longer.
How can I preserve the filters during the pagination? Is it done by adding the result to the argument base? If so, is there another option to pass the parameters by post?

Thanks

Comment: How are you doing the filtering? GET parameters? What is `enable_filter`?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I am filtering by POST, and enable_filter is a parameter that I send to WP_Query to filter the data. The filter is working but not the pagination when I apply the filters.

Comment: Well the problem is using a POST request to filter the query. It’s not what POST is for. You would need each link to send a POST request for the next page, but thats not how links or HTTP works. You’re *retrieving* data, so GET is more appropriate, and in my experience `paginate_links()` will automatically add the GET parameters to the pagination links.

Comment: @JacobPeattie you were right, I changed to GET and the pagination works automatically. Thanks!!!